# What do skill points do?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I wonder what rewards [different skills](http://ratchet.wikia.com/wiki/Ratchet_&_Clank:_All_4_One_skill_point_locations) grant when they are completed. Is what it gives bolts, bonus or simply cheat codes when the game is over?

There are 100 skills points in total. Do I have to successfully complete the 100 for something? Does it work with 10, 20, 25 successful skills?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played the latest R&C but in all previous games skill points were used to unlock skins, concept art, and toggles (mirror world, etc).

Comment: Bolts are used to unlock skins in the more recent games.  Skill points are used for all the other bonus content.

Comment: Good comment! It complements the answer. Does each skill unlocks a bonus? I would be surprised that there have 100! How it works? Did I have to use points to purchase bonus obtained once the game is over?

Answer (score 0):

you unlock cheats with them, things like big head, big weapon, screen alteration, unlimited sprint, unlimited ammo, mirror mode